# Books on algorithms in combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

Hope you are keeping well these days.

Recently, while solving some prove-it type problems in Combinatorics from various contests, I noticed that the solutions used Algorithms like Greedy Algorithm and Invariants, Monovariants, etc.

I would like to know some books that deal with the topics of such algorithms, starting from an elementary level and going up to an advanced level. It would help if the book/resource was concise but explicit and easy to understand.

Again, this is, while focusing on combinatorics, especially problem solving techniques.

Thank you.

Comment: I wrote up notes on [Construction](https://brilliant.org/wiki/construction/), which might be more in line with what you're looking for. Though, what you mentioned are more "problem solving techniques" than algorithms per se. Arthur Engle's problem solving strategies is a good book to look at, esp if you're new to these.

Comment: Thanks sir. I'll check out PSS but do you have more resources with, like a lot of exercises to practice this and a lot of exposition? Tganks nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two nice books that people use in the computer science programming contests, e.g., as organized by ACM,

[Programming Challenges](http://acm.cs.buap.mx/downloads/Programming_Challenges.pdf) where chapter 8 is about [combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638)

[Algorithmic Puzzles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005WSNU84)

Answer (score 0):

Classic 
[Reingold, E.M., Nievergelt, J. and Deo, N., 1977. Combinatorial algorithms: theory and practice. Prentice Hall College Div.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/1096489)